# Dynamic targets based on the dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There are a couple of kind of similar issues but I could not fit any of the proposed concepts to my case.

Just to give a little bit of context: I have a set of Julia files which create plots as PDFs which are part of a make procedure to create scientific papers, something like:

```
plots = $(shell find $(PLOT_PATH)/*.jl | sed 's/\.jl/\.pdf/g')

$(PLOT_PATH)/%.pdf: $(PLOT_PATH)/%.jl $(JULIA_SYSIMAGE)
    $(JL) --project $< -o $(PLOT_PATH)

$(DOCUMENT_FILENAME).pdf: FORCE $(plots) $(figures)
    latexmk $(DOCUMENT_FILENAME).tex
```

In the current setup, each `XYZ.jl` file is creating a `XYZ.pdf` file and it works absolutely fine.

Now I am dealing with cases where it would be much easier to create multiple plots from single Julia files, so a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
using PGFPlotsX
...
...
pgfsave("whatever.pdf")
pgfsave("another.pdf")
pgfsave("yetanother.pdf")
```

so that one could do a `grep pgfsave SCRIPT | awk...` to figure out the targets. However, I could not figure out how to generate dynamic targets (plots) based on the contents of the dependency file (Julia script).

An MWE for my problem is the following: I have a couple of files (dependencies) which are generating a bunch of targets, which are defined inside those files (and can be access via `awk/grep/sed/whatever`). For now, let's say that these are simply `*.txt` files and each line is a target.

**file:** `a.txt`

```
foo
bar
baz
```

**file:** `b.txt`

```
naarf
fjoord
```

A very basic (non-working) manual `Makefile` to demonstrate the goal would be something like this (it does not work as it cannot figure out how to make `foo` etc. but it shows the pattern for `*.txt` which needs to be repeated):

**file:** `Makefile`

```
all_products := $(shell find *.txt | xargs cat)

final_product: $(all_products)
    echo $< > $@

(foo bar baz): a.txt
    touch $(shell cat $<)

(narf fjoord): b.txt
    touch $(shell cat $<)
```

so in principle, I need something to "process" the dependency (`*.txt`) to create a list of the targets, like

```
$(shell cat $%): %.txt
    echo $< > $@
```

but I cannot manage to get a reference to the dependency on the target side (`$%` does not work).

Any ideas? Maybe the whole approach is just a bad idea `;)`

Comment: Perhaps trying to create makefile-fragments dynamically would be the easiest in your situation (https://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/)?

Comment: Huh, yeah I tried that approach but it's really hard to wrap the head around it. I'll try harder and maybe someone has an existing solution meanwhile `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of [GNU make `foreach`, `eval` and `call` functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) is probably what you need. With your example:

```
TXT := $(wildcard *.txt)

.PHONY: all

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

define MY_MACRO
$(1)-targets := $$(shell cat $(1))

$$($(1)-targets): $(1)
    echo $$< > $$@

all: $$($(1)-targets)
endef
$(foreach t,$(TXT),$(eval $(call MY_MACRO,$(t))))
```

(pay attention to the `$$` in the macro definition, they are needed). And then:

```sh
$ make
make
echo a.txt > foo
echo a.txt > bar
echo a.txt > baz
echo b.txt > naarf
echo b.txt > fjoord
```

If you want the recipe to build all targets at once you'll need a recent enough GNU make version (4.3 or later) and its new [rule with grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets) (`x y z&: w`):

```
TXT := $(wildcard *.txt)

.PHONY: all

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

define MY_MACRO
$(1)-targets := $$(shell cat $(1))

$$($(1)-targets)&: $(1)
    touch $$($(1)-targets)

all: $$($(1)-targets)
endef
$(foreach t,$(TXT),$(eval $(call MY_MACRO,$(t))))
```

And then:

```sh
$ make
touch foo bar baz
touch naarf fjoord
```

Note that in this case we could also use a simpler and less GNU make-dependent solution. Just use empty dummy files as time stamps, for instance `.a.txt.tag` for `a.txt`, and a static pattern rule:

```
TXT := $(wildcard *.txt)
TAG := $(patsubst %,.%.tag,$(TXT))

.PHONY: all

all: $(TAG)

$(TAG): .%.tag: %
    touch `cat $<` $@
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am still struggling to fully understand but it kind of works. The only step which is missing and I could not figure out yet is that in my case, I only need to execute one job per `TXT` and it will produce all targets simultaneously, instead of launching it separately for each target. If one of those targets is missing, it should simply call it again and recreate all targets, that's what I tried to abstract with the `touch` command. I thought that having `$$($1)-targets)` would mean that all targets all grouped for the job, but I'll play around...

Comment: No, a rule like: `x y z: w` is the same as 3 independent rules. If you really want one single rule with several targets and which recipe shall build all targets in one single run the best is to use a recent GNU make version and the new [rule with grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets): `x y z &: w`. I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: I am confused because `(foo bar baz): a.txt` worked with `touch $(shell cat $<)` as job. When I delete `bar` for example, it will simply run `touch foo bar baz` again, once. But maybe I misunderstood? (with make 3.8)

Comment: If you have several of `foo bar baz` that must be rebuilt, not just one, the recipe will be executed several times. Give it a try, delete all of them and make again, you'll see. This is why `&:` has been introduced, to tell make that one single run is enough.

Comment: OK I see thanks! The idea with the dummy files is nice, I also had a try where I created some to keep track of the targets but your solution is much more simpler ;)

Comment: Btw. I just tried your example with `&:` and there is a strange behaviour: it reexecutes nicely when I delete `foo` or `bar` but for `baz` it fails. Reproduce it with `make && rm baz && make`. Any idea?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this here with GNU Make 4.3. What version of make do you use? And what do you mean with "_but for baz it fails_"? What happens?

Comment: I run make in a clean folder with `a.txt` and `b.txt`, it produces `foo bar baz narf fjoord`. If I delete `baz` and run `make` again, it complains with `make: *** No rule to make target 'baz', needed by `all'.  Stop.`. The same happens if I delete `fjoord`, so it seems that last target is causing problems.

Comment: Oh damn, sorry, my bad. It was an old terminal session with make 3.8... With 4.3 it works as expected. Anyways, I went with your `TAG` solution, it's better to be "compatible" ;)

Comment: Ah, of course, with make 3.8 the last targets were `baz&` and `fjoord&`, respectively.